# jQuery plugin: Text rotator, changing colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery plugin page:https://github.com/peachananr/simple-text-rotator

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/8msf91wa/

**Please check my external Fiddle, not the code here, it's not working here for some reason.**

I want to change the color of some of the words with my custom css but can't find out how:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".rotate2").textrotator({
  animation: "dissolve", // You can pick the way it animates when rotating through words. Options are dissolve (default), fade, flip, flipUp, flipCube, flipCubeUp and spin.
  separator: ",", // If you don't want commas to be the separator, you can define a new separator (|, &, * etc.) by yourself using this field.
  speed: 2000 // How many milliseconds until the next word show.
});
});
```

```css
span.color1{
  color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-text-rotator/1.0.0/simpletextrotator.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-text-rotator/1.0.0/jquery.simple-text-rotator.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Hey, <span class="rotate2">Friend, <span class="color1">sir</span>, ma'am</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in the [source](https://github.com/peachananr/simple-text-rotator/blob/master/jquery.simple-text-rotator.js#L32) the plugin uses `$.text()` to convert the `.rotate2` element into a text string, therefore all your color markup is silently discarded.
There seems to be no possibility to apply styles to single entries.